# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 : Configure OutputCache attribute to produce Cache-Control: public

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want OutputCache attribute to produce a header with Cache-Control set to public. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code for Attribute will help

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class CacheFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the cache duration in seconds. The default is 10 seconds.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The cache duration in seconds.</value>
        public int Duration {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public CacheFilterAttribute() {
            Duration = 30;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
            if (Duration <= 0) return;

            HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
            TimeSpan cacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration);

            cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(cacheDuration));
            cache.SetMaxAge(cacheDuration);
            cache.AppendCacheExtension("must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
        }
    }
```

and then use [CacheFilter] instead of OutputCache

Comment: one important thing OutputCache filter does - is actually caching the response (server side), will this attribute cache the response (so that Action is not executed on every call)?

Comment: Hi try `[CacheFilter(Duration = 60, Order = 2)] [OutputCache(Duration = 60, Order = 1)] `

Comment: *Gets or sets the cache duration in seconds. The default is 10 seconds.* `public CacheFilterAttribute() {
            Duration = 30;
        }`